# Parameter 0 of constructor in com.dao.impl.EnvironmentPropertyRepositoryImpl required a bean of type 'java.lang.Class' that could not be found

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

I have and Entity `EnvironmentProperty` which has a composite primary Key `EnvironmentPropertyId` (which I have given using `@EmbeddedId`). I have written their Dao Implementation (code is below). But when I am trying to run the code, it gives error :

```
Parameter 0 of constructor in com.visa.dp.ags.probe.api.server.dao.impl.EnvironmentPropertyRepositoryImpl required a bean of type 'java.lang.Class' that could not be found.
```

Following is the code of Dao Interface

```
public interface EnvironmentPropertyRepository extends JpaRepository<EnvironmentProperty, EnvironmentPropertyId> {}
```

Following is the code of the Dao Implementation.

```
@Repository("environmentPropertyRepository")
public class EnvironmentPropertyRepositoryImpl extends SimpleJpaRepository<EnvironmentProperty, EnvironmentPropertyId> implements EnvironmentPropertyRepository {

 public EnvironmentPropertyRepositoryImpl(Class<EnvironmentProperty> domainClass, EntityManager em) {
    super(domainClass, em);
 }
}
```

It is indicationg error at 1st parameter of the constructer which is `domainClass`

I am not able to figure out what I am doing wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Facing the same problem, could you solve it?

Comment: @AlPhaba in the Interface only using Query annotation I gave the HQL statement and I removed the impl.

Comment: Can you show your solution with an example, then we can mark this topic as solved. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a different approach. Instead of Implement the interface and writing the query in the class I gave the query in @Query in the interface only. Didn't get any solution for the above problem.

```
public interface EnvironmentPropertyRepository extends JpaRepository<EnvironmentProperty, EnvironmentPropertyId> {

    @Query( value="SELECT * from {h-schema}TSIC_ENV_PROP where WEB_SVC_ID = ?1 and SVC_ID = ?2 and PARAM_ID = ?3", nativeQuery=true)
    List<EnvironmentProperty> getEnvProp(int webSvcId, int svcId, String paramId);

}
```